Install4J Uninstaller not working on MacOSX M2
The Uninstaller.app installed with application does not work on M2 Macs.
Seeing the following error when executed via the terminal:
+[Launcher displayError:info1:info2:] [Line 154] message AppleJavaMinVersionError not found
Installer was generated with v10.0.9 and bundling a Java 1.8 JRE(Amazon Corretto)
As far as I know Apple has not created a Java version for quite some time now.
Any ideas or pointers would be appreciated.

M2 Macs are fully supported by install4j. In the media wizard, on the "Installer options" step, choose "ARM binaries" or "Universal binaries".

However, the JRE that you bundle is a pre-created bundle for the x64 architecture. In your project, you selected to generate universal binaries. In that case, the JRE has to be a universal binary too. Otherwise, the uninstaller starts as an ARM binary on an ARM Mac, and then it cannot load the JRE.
To solve this problem, do not use pre-created JRE bundles, use generated JRE bundles instead. They will be created as universal bundles with both architectures.
In any case, this showed a failure in error reporting for this situation, we will fix this for the next version.

Thanks @Ingo, but I did have "Universal binaries" selected. I am, however, using a Mac OS X Folder installation, rather than single bundle archive

Sorry, this is indeed something else. Can I download the installer somewhere? You can send the link to support@ej-technologies.com together with the .install4j project file.

Great, will send it shortly. Thank you!

Using generated JRE's worked.
